# Correct hive metastore accessible in spark-shell but not spark-submit file.jar

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hive

When I run

```
spark-shell
```

in linux shell then try:

```
spark.sql("show databases").show()
```

I get the correct list of databases (because I am connected to correct metastore).  Now, when I submit my jar with the following code:

Submit via -

```
spark-submit file.jar
```

Jar code -

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test");
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .config(conf)
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();
spark.sql("show databases").show();
```

My only database listed is default, so it is connected to the wrong hive metastore.  I also tried adding `.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")` to my `spark` object, but same result.  That uri is the same as is `/etc/spark/conf/hive-site.xml` which is all correct.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `--files /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` to your spark-submit command.

Comment: Same result as before.. but if I comment out `SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test");` and remove `.config(conf)` it works.. how can I get around doing this? I would like a SparkConf object.

Comment: It is really weird.